# What should be the Security Pattern for Wallet App?

Tags: user-expectation, security, android

I'm in early stages of developing an Android app for Wallet. I need to be clear about security options I should use. I have a couple of Options listed. Help choose a user-friendly option or suggest one If I miss that on my list.

- Pin Code (Everytime User opens the app it requires a pin code that will be set on first-time use of the app.)
- Fingerprint (I'm in the favor of this feature but I'm not sure if
  most of the devices are capable of fingerprint scanning or not.)

Comment: Is this similar to iOS’ Wallet or is it a different type of application?

Comment: You can support both. Default the use of pin code, and make the use of fingerprints available to users with compatible devices. Let users choose during set-up of the app, or afterwards through the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fingerprint isn't secure, you can find many papers about that but some banking applications use it as an option for compatible smartphones, only if the user entered his PIN at least once.

Pin is a good option.
The numbers must change places with each use. It may be interesting to ask the user for a new PIN code after X connections.

Comment: I would quickly uninstall an application if the service forced me to change my PIN every X connections... That would also actively discourage me from accessing my account. *"If I use a different form of payment, I don't have to be bothered by this app to change my PIN..."*

Comment: I think there is a debate. Privilege security or tranquility. We can meet halfway and just suggest the user to change his pin after X connections.